# Member 'bold()' expects argument of type 'Font'

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a `Text()` view inside my app bar and when i try to make the font bold of the selected item i'm getting this error below:

```
Member 'bold()' expects argument of type 'Font'
```

My Text view:

```
Text("Active")
    .foregroundColor(.white)
    .font(self.index == 0 ? .bold : .none)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `.fontWeight`

```
Text("Active")
   .foregroundColor(.white)
   .fontWeight(self.index == 0 ? .bold : .none)
```

Answer (score 1):

`.bold` is not a `Font` - it's a `Font.Weight`. To fix this, you could either specify the font type (e.g. `body` or `title`), or use the `fontWeight` modifier.

```
Text("Active")
    .foregroundColor(.white)
    .font(self.index == 0 ? .body.bold : .none)
```

```
Text("Active")
    .foregroundColor(.white)
    .fontWeight(self.index == 0 ? .bold : .none)
```

Comment: Is not working, but thanks for your time and your answer :-)

Comment: @GSepetadelis Yeah, only realised after that I made a mistake - sorry!

Comment: No problem, have a nice day!